Is God an artist?
If Man creates art in paintings and sculptures, etc, which are depictions of the natural world such as landscapes flora and fauna, life itself and man accepts and qualifies this to be art.
Is the subject of this art, itself art?
Or is it just man's depiction of the world in painting etc, art, and the natural world is not art?
The proposition that the natural world is not art seems absurd to me.
Is it necessary that the natural world needs an artist, such as paintings and sculptures need an artist?
Is the artist of the natural world God?
If Art is a subjective, and an opinion, and there is no consensus of agreement between everybody with regard to there being objective definition of Art, is anybodies definition of art and there examples of this definition of art, not a depiction of the natural world?
I wondered if there was a christian perspective within the bible or there are Christian apologetics that would concur with my argument?
Or is it flawed?

Is it necessary that the natural world needs an artist isn't this opinion? How is this apologetics?

what is art- is subjective, who an artist- is is subjective

I can't imagine why anyone would deny that God is an artist.

@depperm let me put it another way. Not everybody would have a similar position on their definition of art, but is art from anybodies interpretation, not a depiction of the world itself?

When creative activities cause wonderment, or prompts deeper thinking about what is depicted, there is no disagreeing with the need for intelligence and artistic abilities to combine, both with the originator of what is created, and the beholder.
With God, there are some useful propositions in the Bible, such as:

"The hearing ear, and the seeing eye, the Lord hath made even both of
them." Proverbs 20:12 A.V.
"He that planted the ear, shall he not hear? he that formed the eye,
shall he not see?" Psalm 94:9 A.V.

It follows that being born with senses that enable art to be made and appreciated, the creator of those senses has them himself. He has endowed us with a creative element in us that longs for expression. Art is a great outlet. So, given that God gave us artistic abilities, he must have them himself. He cannot create that which is foreign to his nature and being.
The argument about what is art is irrelevant here. Any artistic endeavor of humans depends first upon the God who is the Original Artist having placed that element within humanity. We are just utilizing the artistic gifts and desires he endowed us with. Yes, the natural world is art itself, arising from the artistry of the Creator.

Is God an artist?
The short answer is absolutely yes.
God is the Great Divine Artist of the whole of creation, both visible and invisible.
The entire natural and physical  is before us as an aide in our contemplation of the Divine himself. Nature and it’s beauty are always before us as a means to contemplate the beauty of God himself.

“The beauty of creation reflects the infinite beauty of the Creator and ought to inspire the respect and submission of man’s intellect and will.” - (Catechism of the Catholic Church, no. 341)

Yes, God is indeed an artist.

“God the Divine Artist became the art – He, Jesus, hung on the wooden frame of the cross. He would provide the inspiration for the future artists in these end-times, and to emblazon buildings and canvases, with a chiaroscuro spectrum of Renaissance thought along the way of centuries" Stephen Bennett.
Art and artisans can change the world, that possibility is seen all around us; through film, art, music, fashion, architecture, social media, digital platforms, an endless list. Yet, creativity is not just for the artist; creativity is at the very heart and centre of Christianity.
In God’s eyes everything is art, He is an artist in every sense of the word, and all things He created are for His purposes. The heavens and the world are a canvas oiled and stretched, for us to walk on, and create in.
Art as an awakening is normal daily fare in our digital world; God’s final purposes for art are at hand in this 21st century. He has many artistic visions to give His artisans on earth. In this book you will get to know God’s character as the Divine Artist, and you can let your art be inspired for His sake.
The Divine Artist

In the woods I encountered the genuineness of the Divine Artist, signs of what is true and genuine that teach me how to remember and recognize the presence of the divine elsewhere. One afternoon last year, I was surprised by the sound of rushing water that sailed through some falls that reminded me of the saving waters of baptism. It was breathtaking.

I think the underlying challenge of this question is the definition of Art.
Even Wikipedia notes:

There is no generally agreed definition of what constitutes art,[4][5][6] and its interpretation has varied greatly throughout history and across cultures.

You could define Art as a human expression that results in a product.
In this case, God is not an artist, because this definition only attributes humans to be able to produce Art.
But here is where Genesis 1,26 comes into the picture:

26 Then God said, “Let us make man[8] in our image, after our likeness.[...]

This means that humans have attributes that mirror Gods. Since we are the creation of God, this means that the ability to do art originates from God.
It also follows from God's omnipotence that God can do art.
So now the question is: If God produces art, what could that be? What could look like?
And this is where I think the idea, that nature is an artistic creation makes a lot of sense because the features of nature and the experiences one can have are much more complex than necessary.
I mean God could've just made a few dots on a piece of paper and called them humans and gave them the ability to love. But no, we have legs, arms, a brain, hair (why do we have hair?), Fingernails, toes,...
I mean one can make the Argument for biological necessity, but I think the argument that God added them for aesthetical reason seem to be valid for me.
Is the artist of the natural world God?
Since you are asking a Christian: Yes.
Why because God created the world, as reported in Genesis 1-2.
However, it depends on how art is defined, which is something where consensus will be difficult if not impossible.

Thanks for your answer. Is it beyond the stretch of imagination that there is human art. However, one defines it, that the subject of the art is not the world itself?
